# What is the difference between soaking and watering thoroughly

Tags: watering

What is the difference between soaking the plant or watering until water flows out of the bottom but not soaking.  It sounds the same to me???

Answer (score 5):

At every plant nursery I've worked at, "soaking" is used as a last ditch attempt to revive a plant that was missed during watering and had "crashed" (complete wilt). This involves filling a 5-gallon pail with water up to the height of the plant's pot and immersing the plant for several hours. Often, this works well enough to keep the plant alive, although it is usually unsalable for a couple of weeks due to die-back of newer growth. "Watering" is just filling the pot with water and letting it drain normally.

The context in which you read the word "soaking" is important - was the author talking about indoor plants or outdoor plants? Did they write something like "Give the plant a good soak..." and if so, why did they want you to soak the plant? Perhaps they (or their editor) were trying to avoid repeating "water the plant weekly" and thought that "soak" was a good synonym? Often, authors aren't as knowledgeable as they pretend to be, in which case they use common terms incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that a pot which is way too dry will run water out the bottom while absorbing very little of the water going through it. The same pot, immersed in a bucket or tray for some time, will take on more water.

So, if you weighed a hypothetical pair of dried out pots, ran water through one, soaked the other and then let it drain what dripped out freely after soaking, the soaked one would weigh more, because it would retain more water and be on the path to not being so dried out.

If a pot is **not** excessively dried out, there's less difference, as water uptake is not so impaired.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see what you read but how I define soaking as immersing the item in water for a period of time.  i.e. soak bare roots for 2 hours, soak seeds for 24 hours.

I think that is different than when somebody says "soak it with water" which is more slang for water it a whole lot.